# How to reindex resampled pandas DataFrame with missing dates keeping current values

Tags: python, django, pandas

I have a dataframe whose index is a subset days of a month. I want to add all the days, from 1st to last, filling not existing values to 0 and keeping existing ones.

I've tried with reindex, but all tries ends with missing data.

This is my sample DataFrame:

```
checkin_date                    checkout_date        duration              
0 2019-05-20 08:48:09.630928+00:00 2019-05-20 09:51:55.130997+00:00  01:03:45.500069
1 2019-05-20 08:39:12.660055+00:00 2019-05-20 09:51:55.130997+00:00 01:12:42.470942
2 2019-05-19 16:38:15.195097+00:00 2019-05-20 08:20:49.860755+00:00 15:42:34.665658
3 2019-05-19 16:20:29.513691+00:00 2019-05-20 07:41:46.928414+00:00 15:21:17.414723
4 2019-05-07 12:06:02.255836+00:00 2019-05-07 17:30:22.550536+00:00 05:24:20.294700
5 2019-05-07 11:00:19.765565+00:00 2019-05-07 11:10:33.792748+00:00 00:10:14.027183
```

I do this to resample:

```
df.set_index('checkin_date').resample('D').sum()
```

which gives me the DataFrame from first existing date in the month to last existing date:

```
                                    duration
checkin_date                                    
2019-05-07 00:00:00+00:00 0 days 05:34:34.321883
2019-05-08 00:00:00+00:00        0 days 00:00:00
2019-05-09 00:00:00+00:00        0 days 00:00:00
2019-05-10 00:00:00+00:00        0 days 00:00:00
2019-05-11 00:00:00+00:00        0 days 00:00:00
2019-05-12 00:00:00+00:00        0 days 00:00:00
2019-05-13 00:00:00+00:00        0 days 00:00:00
2019-05-14 00:00:00+00:00        0 days 00:00:00
2019-05-15 00:00:00+00:00        0 days 00:00:00
2019-05-16 00:00:00+00:00        0 days 00:00:00
2019-05-17 00:00:00+00:00        0 days 00:00:00
2019-05-18 00:00:00+00:00        0 days 00:00:00
2019-05-19 00:00:00+00:00 1 days 07:03:52.080381
2019-05-20 00:00:00+00:00 0 days 02:16:27.971011
```

Which is perfect. But I need to complete the DataFrame with the missing dates of the month: the first days and the last days.

So I try something like that to reindex:

```
idx = pd.date_range(datetime(year=2019, month=5, day=1), datetime(year=2019, month=5, day=31))
df.reindex(idx, fill_value=0)
```

At first, this last command results in zeros at all the cells. I've tried reformating df index or idx but nothing works.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DatetimeIndex.tz_localize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.tz_localize.html):

```
df1 = (df.set_index('ckin_date')
         .resample('D')
         .sum()
         .reindex(idx.tz_localize('UTC'), fill_value=0))
```

---

```
print (df1)

                                        duration
2019-05-01 00:00:00+00:00        0 days 00:00:00
2019-05-02 00:00:00+00:00        0 days 00:00:00
2019-05-03 00:00:00+00:00        0 days 00:00:00
2019-05-04 00:00:00+00:00        0 days 00:00:00
2019-05-05 00:00:00+00:00        0 days 00:00:00
2019-05-06 00:00:00+00:00        0 days 00:00:00
2019-05-07 00:00:00+00:00 0 days 05:34:34.321883
2019-05-08 00:00:00+00:00        0 days 00:00:00
2019-05-09 00:00:00+00:00        0 days 00:00:00
2019-05-10 00:00:00+00:00        0 days 00:00:00
2019-05-11 00:00:00+00:00        0 days 00:00:00
2019-05-12 00:00:00+00:00        0 days 00:00:00
2019-05-13 00:00:00+00:00        0 days 00:00:00
2019-05-14 00:00:00+00:00        0 days 00:00:00
2019-05-15 00:00:00+00:00        0 days 00:00:00
2019-05-16 00:00:00+00:00        0 days 00:00:00
2019-05-17 00:00:00+00:00        0 days 00:00:00
2019-05-18 00:00:00+00:00        0 days 00:00:00
2019-05-19 00:00:00+00:00 1 days 07:03:52.080381
2019-05-20 00:00:00+00:00 0 days 02:16:27.971011
2019-05-21 00:00:00+00:00        0 days 00:00:00
2019-05-22 00:00:00+00:00        0 days 00:00:00
2019-05-23 00:00:00+00:00        0 days 00:00:00
2019-05-24 00:00:00+00:00        0 days 00:00:00
2019-05-25 00:00:00+00:00        0 days 00:00:00
2019-05-26 00:00:00+00:00        0 days 00:00:00
2019-05-27 00:00:00+00:00        0 days 00:00:00
2019-05-28 00:00:00+00:00        0 days 00:00:00
2019-05-29 00:00:00+00:00        0 days 00:00:00
2019-05-30 00:00:00+00:00        0 days 00:00:00
2019-05-31 00:00:00+00:00        0 days 00:00:00
```